# How to print process ıd in event log?

Tags: powershell, parsing, scripting, windows-scripting, get-eventlog

Im trying to get process id from my Get-Eventlog. I can not parse the process id from the message. How ı can get it from there ? I tried With Select string -Pattern but it did not worked. My powershell code :

```
$directory = E:\BpLnfgDsc2.txt
$message = Get-EventLog -log Security -InstanceId 4663 -Newest 1 | Where {$_.message -match "Object Name:\s*$directory"}  | foreach {$_.Message}
```

And here is my output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $message
An attempt was made to access an object.

Subject:
        Security ID:            Some-id
        Account Name:           tester
        Account Domain:         DESKTOP
        Logon ID:               Some-Id

Object:
        Object Server:          Security
        Object Type:            File
        Object Name:            E:\BpLnfgDsc2.txt
        Handle ID:              Some-Id
        Resource Attributes:    S:AI

Process Information:
        Process ID:             0xd34
        Process Name:           C:\Windows\explorer.exe

Access Request Information:
        Accesses:               %%4423

        Access Mask:            0x80
```

My expected output:

***0xd34***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your regex matching pattern a bit more to also capture the process ID and output it with the automatically populated variable `$matches`.

I've chosen a capture group name for clarity, you could also just use number captured groups. I also added `(?s)` at the beginning of the pattern to treat the multiline message string as a single line

```
$message = Get-EventLog -log Security -InstanceId 4663 -Newest 1 |
    Where-Object {$_.message -match "(?s)Object Name:\s*$directory.+Process ID:\s+(?<ProcessID>\S+)"}  |
        ForEach-Object {$matches.ProcessID}
```